Python pdb failing to stop in a unittest test
I am trying to debug a unit test using the unittest framework, and the command line pdb debugger. This is an example program (DBTesting.py):
import pymysql

class DBTesting:
    def __init__(self):
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='test', password='test', user='test', database='test')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('Select * from mystuff')

        for row in cursor:
            print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db_test = DBTesting()

And the test (DBTestingTest.py):
import unittest
import DBTesting
from unittest import mock


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('builtins.print')
    @mock.patch('DBTesting.pymysql.connect')
    def test_db_mock(self, mock_conn, mock_print):
        mock_cursor = mock_conn.return_value.cursor.return_value
        mock_cursor.__iter__.return_value = [['1', '2', '3']]
        db_test = DBTesting.DBTesting()
        mock_print.assert_called_with(['1', '2', '3'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

If I debug with pycharm, and put a breakpoint on the program at line 10 of DBTesting.py on the print(row) statement, everything happens as expected, and the program stops, allowing me to see the variables as usual. If running with python3 -m pdb and then setting a breakpoint with b DBTesting.py:10 and pressing c to continue, the debugger stops, but none of the commands such as l or a return a listing or variable.
Is this happening because I'm not running the test with e.g. python3 -m unittest DBTestingTest.py? What would be the correct way to unittest and debug with the command line debugger?
